# Correl function with #N/A values

Tags: excel

I would like to calculate the correlation between two ranges. The first range contains all values, the second range has some values missing (#N/A). Each range has about 4,000 values, i.e., B1:B4000 and G1:G4000. An example for the missing values is:

```
1      2
3      5
2.5    3.4 
5      #N/A
6      4
```

I tried the following formula:

```
=correl(range1,range2)
```

This gives me the result #N/A.

Then I tried the following:

```
=correl(if(iserror(range1),"",range1),if(iserror(range2),"",range2))
```

This also gives me the result #N/A.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you entering the second formula with `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter`?

Comment: Right... Totally forget to check that. That was it. The second formula works find. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be an array formula.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

If done correctly, **braces** will appear in the Formula Bar.